# SharePoint Designer 2007 - Send Email: The whitespace inside a hyperlink tag changes to plus (+)

Tags: sharepoint, designer

I am using SharePoint Designer 2007 to send custom task notification.

The lookup values retail their whitespaces if they are not part of the quotations in the html hyperlink tag.
However, if a lookup value is part of the tag (example link), the whitespaces inside the quotations are changed into plus (+) sign.

Any ideas on this?

Thanks.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

> quotations in the html hyperlink tag

I am assuming your talking about

```
<a href="SomeURLHere">Some link<a>
```

You can't use spaces in URL's - they have to be escaped with with + or %20

So

http://someserver/some page.aspx

is invalid and needs to be

http://someserver/some+page.aspx
or
http://someserver/some%20page.aspx

Why would you want to send an invalid url?